# seperate emails from combined emails in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

In my text file some of the lines have combined with multiple email address. How can separate them using Regex in notepad++?

```
amannityo@gmail.comamannityo@gmail.com,
vinformax.tevisurya@gmail.com,
tevisurya@empowercsi.cominformax.tevisurya@gmail.com,
informax.tevisurya@gmail.com,
tevisurya@empowercsi.cominformax.tevisurya@gmail.com,
```

separate them into next line or space in between

Comment: With difficulty if they don't all end in .com ?

Comment: but we can .com,.net,.org for some. if any domain missing I can add later in Regex

Comment: Naively you could find `(\.com|\.net|\.org)` replace with `$1\r\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace an email if there is a second email behind it. Say that at the moment each email ends in `.com` or `.org` and you can later extend the list of possible domains `(\.com|\.org|...)`. But to keep things simple lets use `(\.com|\.org)` at the moment.

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(\.com|\.org)(.*@)`
- **Replace With:** `\1\r\n\2`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All
- keep clicking Replace All until no more replacements are done (e.g. if there are some line with three or four emails), each Replace All splits off the first email. You can keep ALT-A pressed.